# Serialize Eloquent collection append sometimes

Tags: laravel, serialization, collections, eloquent

I want to add value from accessor to collection in specific cases. There is array `$appends` for it, but I don't want to add the values always. Maybe is there a method like `makeVisible` for it?

Lets imagine I have models **Book** and **Author**:

```
class Book extends Model
{ 
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'author_id'];

    public function author() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Author::class);
    }

    public function getAuthorNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->author->name;
    }
}
```

And I want to return books collection with author name just call:

```
Route::get('books', function () {
   return App\Book::all()
      ->appends(['author_name']);
});
```

And yes I'm able to use `map()` but I just find another (more beautiful decision)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Laravel eloquent has a method called [makeVisible()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json).

> If you would like to make some typically hidden attributes visible on
>   a given model instance, you may use the makeVisible method. The
>   makeVisible method returns the model instance for convenient method
>   chaining.